# Java: Method/Constructor argument validation. Also should there be multiple validation calls?

Tags: java, validation, methods

I have a question about validating method/constructor arguments.

Let´s say I have a class `BankAccount`. This class performs some basic validation in the constructor (Note: that´s not how I would implement such a class, it´s better to use polymorphism and interface implementations for providing different types of bank accounts. Here an enum `BankAccount.Type` is used).

```
BankAccount(Type type, double balance, String ownerName, String accountNumber) {
    // Make sure no invalid arguments are passed.
    if (type == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'type' may not be null!");
    }
    if (balance < type.getBalanceLimit()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("initial 'balance' may not be less than the accounts balance limit!");
    }
    if (ownerName == null || ownerName.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'ownerName' may not be null or empty!");
    }
    if (!type.requiresOwner()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create an account with an owner if that account type does not require an owner!");
    }
    if (accountNumber == null || accountNumber.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'accountNumber' may not be null or empty!");
    }

    this.type = type;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}
```

**First of all:** Is this the way to go when validating constructor arguments or is it preferable to set all the fields first and then call a method validateState() which checks if the constructed state is valid and else throws an exception. Something like this:

```
BankAccount(Type type, double balance, String ownerName, String accountNumber) {
        this.type = type;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;

        validateState();
    }
```

**Which one of the above solutions is preferable (in most situations)?**

The 2nd part of my question is about repeated validation. Let´s say I have a class `Bank`. This class has a method `createGiroAccount(Account.Type type, String ownerName)`

```
/**
         * Creates a new {@link Account} of the specified {@link Account.Type} for the given owner.
         * Note that the {@link Account.Type} must be a giro account type.
         *
         * @param type      the type of the new account which must be one of the available giro options, not null
         * @param ownerName the owner´s name who owns the new account, not null or empty
         */
        public void createGiroAccount(BankAccount.Type type, String ownerName) {
            // Really basic validation
            if (type == null || !type.isGiro()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'type' may not be null and must be of type giro!");
            }
            if (ownerName == null || ownerName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'ownerName' may not be null or empty");
            }

            String accountNumber = generateUniqueAccountNumber();
            accounts.add(new BankAccount(type, ownerName, accountNumber));
        }
```

**My question:** Should there too be a validation of arguments, even if the `BankAccount` validates the arguments/state anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the way to go when validating constructor arguments or is it preferable to set all the fields first and then call a method validateState()

You can create [custom annotation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html) and to check the validity of the parameters if you don't want to write repeating code.

> The 2nd part of my question is about repeated validation.

If you have only one constructor then check is not needed in `createGiroAccount`. Otherwise you do.

Comment: So assuming I have a bank account factory/service that is responsible for creating new bank accounts and I only expose that factory (and not the BankAccount´s constructor), then it would be enough to validate in the factory methods and keep the constructor completely "stupid"?

Comment: @Elias Nope. If there's only one constructor then you'll be able to create object through that constructor only. Thus check is needed on that constructor only.

Comment: Ok, so to be really safe in case the factory itself passes some invalid arguments?

Comment: Yeah almost :) But what do you mean by modifying members with getter methods? Do you mean when the getter returns an object reference?

Comment: Sorry, it'll be setter only ;)
  factory will pass invalid arguments only if you modify the members via setter methods

Answer (score 1):

Having the validation within the constructor or in a dedicated method?

Both solutions are okay.

The trick is that if you add a lot of validation code into the constructor, mixed with the proper constructors code, it could be harder to maintain.

By the way if you choose to have a dedicated method  `validateState();` you should call it before doing anything into the contructor, it's useless to process code and later figure that one of your parameters is not valid and throw an exception....

If you want to have a clean validation you can use the `javax.validation` package. see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation003.htm)

You can then create your proper annotation an annotated your constructor parameters.

```
BankAccount(Type type, @ValidBalance double balance, @NotEmpty String ownerName, @NotEmpty String accountNumber) {
```

Where `@ValidBalance` will be a custom validation.

Comment: validateState(); you should call it before doing anything into the constructor: Do you mean I would have to call it at the beginning of a constructor? Because that doesn´t make sense to me. In this example it is shown exactly like my above example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=19C1AF72A4087F2D186A373E38411A0C?Id=6      So I guess you meant something different. Could you please clarify this :)

Comment: The example is okay. You first set your attributes whith what you received as parameters and then you call the validation method. By the way the validation method requires the attributes to be initialized, right? I was saying this for example if your constructor is doing more than just settings the attributes...

Comment: That makes sense now. Because then it would really make no sense to perform validation at the end. And regarding `javax.validation`: Is this nowadays the goto solution when validating simpler arguments? Because it´s really short and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do it, and none of them "right". In real-life systems, you'd have things like DB connection frameworks and REST APIs which assume you'll be using classes that don't have any arguments in the constructor at all.

So what you would probably have is an `interface Account` that can't have any validation anyway.

```
interface BackAccount {
    AccountType getAccountType();
    BigDecimal getBalance();
    Person getOwner();
}
```

Note that the owner is of a different class than `String`; this allows to assume that if you ever have a `BankAccount`, you won't need to validate the owner because `Person` validation happens when you create that object. You'd probably have a validation framework with something like

```
interface Validator<T> {
    boolean isValid(T toValidate);
}
```

which would allow you to implement validation for Persons, BankAccounts etc. In your case, you'd have a

```
class TypeBalanceValidator<BankAccount> implements Validator<BankAccount> {
    public boolean isValid(BankAccount account) {
        return account.getBalance().compareTo(getMinBalanceForType(account.getType())) > 0;
    }
}
```

As for creating the `BankAccount`, apart from automatically reading from a database, you'd probably have a `Service` which provides a factory method, not unlike yours, but with something like

```
interface AccountService {
    BankAccount createGiroAccount(Person p);
}
```

Why would you even pass the type to a method that only allows AccountType.GIRO? Anyway, this is where you'd create `BankAccount`s and where the validation would take place.

Comment: Ok, I get your idea.  But when would the validator be used/called? Always when there is the need to validate a bank account (e.g. after loading from DB)? And to clarify why I´ve passed in the account type to `createGiroAccount(...)`, it is because there are different types of giro accounts (e.g. Student Giro, Normal Giro, Minor Giro, etc.). Also, this project is just a simple one for school but I was just curious how this could look like in the "real-world" :)

Comment: @Elias I guess mostly validators are injected per annotations like in Nirekin's answer; you'd have a `setBalance(@ValidBalance BigDecimal value)` method and some framework magic (ie usually an "aspect") will look up what that means and call it with the appropriate parameters. It was kind of obvious that this was a school or private project, we've all been there ;) Keep going.

Comment: Wow, I am just surprised how compact and readable this notation is (with annotations). Maybe overkill for my purpose right now but definitely looking into that later on. And regarding the project, the task is to create a "next-gen" banking system - pretty funny though :)

Comment: @Elias it's very readable, but once you run into problems it can be hard to track down, because the error occurs outside the code you're actually calling.

Comment: So the error just tells me that inside the validator class an exception was thrown but not for which specific method call where there was an argument annotated with that validator?

Comment: It really depends, but usually the validator would create a result or throw an Exception that the framework handles properly. What I meant was if there was an error in the validator itself, which may throw an exception that doesn't get caught and then seemingly comes out of nowhere somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161696/discussion-between-elias-and-daniu).

Comment: @Elias Sorry, no time, can only put in these answers in between pretending to work ;)

Comment: Ohh sorry. Nevermind then, thanks for your huge help :)